# Custom Addon is visible in N panel only if there are objects in the scene. How can I make it persistent even if there are no scene objects?

Tags: python, interface, panel

My question is basically the title. I have to create an object first before my custom N panel shows up. I want to be able to make it (or some fields within it) visible even if no object is in the scene.

Here is my code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Cultmethod Sandbox",
    "author": "Jay",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "3D View",
    "description": "Cultmethod Sandbox",
    "category": "Development"
}
 
import bpy
import colorsys
import bmesh

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Menu,
                       Operator,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Operators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CULT_SetUpSuzanne(Operator):
    bl_label = "Place a Suzanne"
    bl_idname = "object.create_suzanne"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=3, relative=False)
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
        #bpy.context.space_data.context = 'MODIFIER'
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Subdivision")
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 1.25323), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, False, True), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class CULT_ClearParentKeep(Operator):
    bl_label = "Clear Parent and Keep Transform"
    bl_idname = "object.clear_parent_keep"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        sel_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
        for obj in sel_objs:
            bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM')
        return {'FINISHED'}


class CULT_ClearAnimData(Operator):
    bl_label = "Clear Animation Data"
    bl_idname = "object.clear_anim_data"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        sel_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
        #bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        for obj in sel_objs:
            bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_clear_v3d()
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CULT_ResetViewportDisplay(Operator):
    bl_label = "Reset Viewport Color"
    bl_idname = "object.reset_viewport_disp"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        selected_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects
        active_obj = bpy.context.active_object

        for x in selected_obj:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            x.select_set(True)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = x
            if x.type == 'MESH':
                for mat in x.data.materials:
                    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0, 0, 0.906)
                    color4 = (color[0], color[1], color[2], 1)
                    try:
                        mat.diffuse_color = color4
                    except:
                        print("Can\'t change viewport material color")
            
        # Select again objects
        for j in selected_obj:
            j.select_set(True)
        
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = active_obj

        return {'FINISHED'}

class CULT_RecalcNormalsSelected(Operator):
    bl_label = "Recalculate Normals Outside"
    bl_idname = "object.recalc_normals_selected"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bm = bmesh.new()
        meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
        for mesh in meshes:
            bm.from_mesh(mesh)
            bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
            bm.to_mesh(mesh)
            bm.clear()
            mesh.update()

        bm.free()

        return {'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Cultmethod"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Cultmethod"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        layout.operator("object.clear_anim_data")
        layout.operator("object.reset_viewport_disp")
        layout.operator("object.clear_parent_keep")
        layout.operator("object.recalc_normals_selected")
        layout.operator("object.create_suzanne")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    CULT_ClearParentKeep,
    CULT_ClearAnimData,
    CULT_ResetViewportDisplay,
    CULT_RecalcNormalsSelected,
    CULT_SetUpSuzanne,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any help at all would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Remove the poll function if you want the panel to be displayed at all times.

---

It seems that you've unintentionally used a `poll` function for your `OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel` panel. The `poll` function for panels and operators is used to check if the `execute` function is allowed to be run. If `poll` returns `true` it can be executed, otherwise not. For panels this has the effect that they aren't drawn when `poll` returns `false`.

The implementation of `OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel` contains the following `poll` function.

```
    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None
```

It checks if there is currently any object referenced by `bpy.context.object`. If there are no objects in the scene or you've deleted the previously active one, then its value is `None` and thus the return value is `false`. Therefore, the panel will not be displayed. If you don't want this behavior and always display the panel, remove the `poll` function. This is equivalent to having a `poll` function that always returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Going to implement it now.

Comment: Is there a way to implement an independent poll function for each operator so that a specific feature grays out or disappears if it isn't relevant? Or is that not the correct way to do this?

Comment: @Jay Sure, that's possible when you are implementing your own operators that are displayed in the panel. You can define the poll for them however you like as well.